# React ignores layout style whenever I navigate to another page

Tags: reactjs

I am building a website using React.
I am using Router from 'react-router-dom' to navigate between pages (urls).

Everything seems to work ok, but if I navigate between pages the layout style sometimes changes. For instance, the workouts page layout seems good and as I want, however, if I navigate from there to Gallery page and back, it looks different. Same goes for other pages.

I am adding a link to my Github page (the updated code is under 'main' branch). Also, you'll find beneath two pictures that demonstrate the different layout of the Workout page.

[image: How it suppose to look]

[image: How it looks sometimes]

My Github repository [Link](https://github.com/saharc576/Shez-up/tree/main/src).

**Notice that sometimes it doesn't change the style, perhaps you will need to register, login, and logout.**

***Any Help will be appreciated!!***

Comment: Your repo is private, so it's inaccessible. It's also better if you shared the relevant code instead of the entire repo.

Comment: Sorry, just made it public. The thing is I have no idea what is the relevant code... which part do you think I should share? It involves many components

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From peeking at your repo, my first guess would be that the problem is your css classes aren't scoped and are overruling each other when you render different components. When you import a css file like you do, it applies the rules globally, so depending on the order of the components you render, the rules are applied to all components in a different order. What you should do is:

1. Change your CSS file names to include `module` , for example `Workouts.css` should be become `Workouts.module.css`
2. Make your CSS imports act like a module, for example `import styles from '../css/Workouts.module.css'`
3. Change all your classes in the component to be from `styles`, for example replace `<div className="row">` with `<div className={styles.row}>`

This way, if you have more than one component with the same class name, the rules of the class apply only to this specific component (i.e. scoped css)

That's my guess